# Why does the half-moon symbolize timelessness in Hinduism?

Tags: scripture, shiva, symbolism, moon

I've often seen Lord Shiva with 'half-moon' on his head which, I was told, as the timelessness of Lord Shiva; meaning Lord Shiva is beyond 'time' or he's the master of time and space as per Hindu sources.

But why does specifically the 'half-moon' symbolize this?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Why is Moon on Lord Shiva's head only shown as crescent?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11036/647) ?

Comment: I think that answer is a little contradictory/different from the accepted answer to this question. M happy to learn two different points of views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crescent moon symbolizes the time cycle and not timelessness. The moon goes from the new moon to the full moon and back. Hence it symbolizes a cycle.

> The crescent moon is shown on the side of the Lord's head as an
> ornament and not an integral part of His countenance. **The waxing and
> waning phenomenon of the moon symbolizes the time cycle through which
> creation evolves from the beginning to the end.** Since Lord is the
> Eternal Reality, the crescent moon is only one of His ornaments and
> not an integral part of Him.

**The Hindu Mind by Bansi Pandit**